# Associate event struct to user addresses

Tags: solidity, contract-design, storage, mapping, struct

I have two contracts. One called User and other called Event

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract User {

    mapping(uint=>address) addresses;
    uint addressRegistryCount;   
}
```

---

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
import './User.sol';

contract Event is User{

    struct EventStruct {
        uint average;
        uint quantity;
    }

    mapping(uint=>EventStruct) events;
    uint eventsCounter;
}
```

I have a mapping in bouth smart-contract´s that save the items. But I don´t know how to reference that each item, are part of a specified existing user of the mapping addresses inside the User contract.

I inherit the User contract inside the Event but i don´t how can I associate

Comment: Your question is unclear IMO, but you can start by declaring each one of the state variables in contract `User` as `internal`, so that you can access them in contract `Event`.

Comment: I mean. In one side I have addresses mapped by a id. And in other events mapped by id´s. Is possible to associate the events to the existing addresses?

Comment: Why don't you just map each address to an event?

Comment: because one user can have more than one event

Comment: Your scheme is unclear to me. How exactly are ids, addresses and events refer to each other in your system? What is the relational model?

Comment: the ids are simple uint, that increment each time that a new event/user appear in the contract. That works fine. When i generate a user a user is added to the mapping with a basic id that start in 0 and goes incrementing each time that appear a new user (same to events). But i cant get the users events, because i dont know how to relation bouth things

Comment: You need to refactor the storage layout to support the requirement. This would be a lengthy explanation, so have a look at this. You will probably need to glance at the two linked posts for prior knowledge so it makes sense. https://medium.com/@robhitchens/enforcing-referential-integrity-in-ethereum-smart-contracts-a9ab1427ff42

Comment: Thankyou that was the key "One-To-Many". Im going to get a look

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little sketch of a minimal approach. It's just an illustration to give you some ideas. No warranty ;-)

```
pragma solidity 0.5.2;

contract Users {

    mapping(address=>bool) public isUser;
    address[] public users;

    function register() public {
        require(!isUser[msg.sender]);
        isUser[msg.sender] = true;
        users.push(msg.sender);
    }
}

contract Events {

    uint eventCount;

    struct EventStruct {
        mapping(address=>bool) isAttendee;
        address[] attendees;
        bytes32 metadata;
    }

    mapping(uint=>EventStruct) public events;

    function createEvent(bytes32 metaData) public {
        events[eventCount].metadata = metaData;
        eventCount++;
    }

    function reserveAttenance(uint eventId) public {
        require(eventId < eventCount);
        EventStruct storage e = events[eventId];
        require(!e.isAttendee[msg.sender]);
        e.isAttendee[msg.sender] = true;
        e.attendees.push(msg.sender);
    }
}
```

I set several concerns aside for clarity and made some assumptions. There is no access control and we just assume that attendees will self sign-up. There is no delete possibility. I added `metaData` to the `struct` to show where additional information might be stored.

Hope it helps.